# Is there a way to Remove entites from database by Id in a single line without iterating each?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq

I have a List of strings `List<string>` which I get from the following method `var sentNotifications = Smtp.ProcessItems(queue, SmtpConfiguration);`

I can do this now:

```
        foreach (var notification in sentNotifications)
        {
            //Retrieve entity by id
            //Remove entity
        }
```

But I would not like that. Can I somehow retrieve all entities in a group? And delete them all at the same time?

Comment: EF Core 7 has ExecuteDelete...

Answer (score 1):

If you can use **`EF 7.0`** then here is the bulk delete:

```cs
context.Notifications
           .Where(r => ids.Any(id => id == r.Id))
           .ExecuteDelete();
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer:

```
  _dbContext.Notifications.RemoveRange(_dbContext
           .Notifications
           .Where(r => ids.Any(id => id == r.Id)));
```